# How to accept any variable type that can be used in SwiftUI Text view

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, string-interpolation

I'm trying to create a reusable component for presenting a Swift collections OrderedSet into a SwiftUI List with delete, move and add handlers.

I would like to be able to pass in an OrderedSet of any type that can be used directly as interpolated string, for example `Text("hello \(myGenericTypeLikeAStringIntOrFloat) world")`.

I've been trying to find a protocol that can help me define these generic types and thought perhaps the `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` could help here but I think thats only used to create your own types that can be used in SwiftUI Text views.

The error I'm getting on the `Text("\(item)")` line is `No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'`.

Is there a way to adjust my OrderedSet to only accept items that can be used in Text views?

Here's a stripped down example that hopefully explains it better.

```
import SwiftUI
import OrderedCollections


struct ReusableListView<Element: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var set: OrderedSet<Element>
    
    @State private var multiSelection: Set<Element> = []
    
    init(_ set: Binding<OrderedSet<Element>>) {
        self._set = set
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            List(selection: $multiSelection) {
                ForEach(set, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    set.elements.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @State private var setWithStrings: OrderedSet<String> = ["hello", "world"]
    @State private var setWithInts: OrderedSet<Int> = [1, 2, 3]
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ReusableListView($setWithStrings)
            ReusableListView($setWithInts)
        }
    }
}
```

*** Added full working code snippet after excellent answer from @Joakim-Danielson ***

```swift
import SwiftUI
import OrderedCollections

protocol TextSupport {
    var text: String { get }
}

extension String: TextSupport {
    var text: String { self }
}

extension Int: TextSupport {
    var text: String { self.formatted() }
}

struct ReusableListView<Element: Hashable & TextSupport>: View {
    
    @Binding var set: OrderedSet<Element>
    
    @State private var multiSelection: Set<Element> = []
    
    init(_ set: Binding<OrderedSet<Element>>) {
        self._set = set
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            List(selection: $multiSelection) {
                ForEach(set, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item.text)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    set.elements.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @State private var setWithStrings: OrderedSet<String> = ["hello", "world"]
    @State private var setWithInts: OrderedSet<Int> = [1, 2, 3]
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ReusableListView($setWithStrings)
            ReusableListView($setWithInts)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is localisation a concern for you? If not, you can just do `Text(String(describing: item))`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that and indeed seems to work nicely for ints and strings! I did end up going with the custom TextSupport protocol as described by @joakim-danielson as that will allow me to be more flexible with the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to introduce a protocol that the generic type must conform to and that `Text` can take advantage of

```
protocol TextSupport {
    var text: String { get }
}
```

Then we change the declaration of the view to

```
struct ReusableListView<Element: Hashable & TextSupport>: View
```

and use the property in the view

```
ForEach(set, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item.text)")
}
```

Then you need to conform to the protocol for any type you use

```
extension String: TextSupport {
    var text: String { self }
}
extension Int: TextSupport {
    var text: String { self.formatted() }
}
```

---

Another option is to add a closure property to the view so that each implementation of the view passes its own way of converting the `Element` type to a `String`

```
var convert: (Element) -> String
```

the property is set in the init

```
init(_ set: Binding<OrderedSet<Element>>, convert: @escaping (Element) -> String) {
    self._set = set
    self.convert = convert
}
```

and use it in the `ForEach`

```
ForEach(set, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(convert(item))")
}
```

And then you call the view with a closure

```
ReusableListView($setWithStrings) { $0 }
ReusableListView($setWithInts) { $0.formatted() }
```

Comment: Unrelated perhaps but why not declare the selection property as `Set<Element>`?

Comment: That was a mistake indeed, should have been Set<Element>